# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library pdo_Oci.so

Tags: php

I recently found that the error logs of all the pages I have on a VPS with cloudlinux are full of messages like this one:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_oci.so' -
>   /opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_oci.so: cannot
>   open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line
>   0

I have searched extensively trying to find how can I disable this library or extension because I don't have it. I have changed the PHP versions and the error logs keep showing this error.

Comment: Please note that we have no way to know what you've tried or haven't tried unless you tell us. Disabling a PHP extension is pretty straightforward, it probably won't help you that someone copies into a answer box what you've possibly done already.

Comment: Find and modify your php.ini file and comment out the line that contains `pdo_oci.so` but putting a semi-colon in front of it (`;pdo_oci.so').